# sp_columns for different schemas

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I don't remember how but I remember that before when I was executing sp_columns for one specific table, I get the result of columns for that table no matter the schema.

For example I have `auth.roles` and `oper.roles`, if I do:

```
sp_columns roles
```

I should have records for both schemas but now I receive only one. Is there anything I need to setup on SQL Server? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

exec sp_columns '***tablename***', @table_owner ='***schemaname***'

e.g. exec sp_columns '***roles***', @table_owner ='***auth***'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return data for all tables regardless of the schema then you need to use a wildcard for the `@table_owner` parameter:

```
EXECUTE sp_columns @table_name = 'Roles', @table_owner = '%';
```

**EDIT**

The only way I can see to return objects from all schemas is to use pattern matching on the objectname:

```
EXECUTE sp_columns @table_name = '%Roles';
```

The obvious pitfall being that this will also return a table like 'dbo.UserRoles' even though this may not be what is required.

From the [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176077.aspx):

**[@table_owner=] owner**

> Is the object owner of the object that is used to return catalog information. owner is nvarchar(384), with a default of NULL. Wildcard pattern matching is supported. If owner is not specified, the default object visibility rules of the underlying DBMS apply.
>
> If the current user owns an object with the specified name, the columns of that object are returned. If owner is not specified and the current user does not own an object with the specified object, sp_columns looks for an object with the specified object owned by the database owner. If one exists, that object's columns are returned.

Furthermore I have looked at the definition of the procedure `master.dbo.sp_columns`, and extracted some relevant parts below:

```
CREATE procedure [sys].[sp_columns]
(
    @table_name         nvarchar(384),
    @table_owner        nvarchar(384) = null,
    @table_qualifier    sysname = null,
    @column_name        nvarchar(384) = null,
    @ODBCVer            int = 2
)
as
    declare @full_table_name    nvarchar(769) -- 384 + 1 + 384
    declare @table_id           int
    declare @fUsePattern        bit

    select @fUsePattern = 1
    select @full_table_name = isnull(quotename(@table_owner), '') + '.' + isnull(quotename(@table_name), '')
    select @table_id = object_id(@full_table_name)

    if (@fUsePattern = 1) -- Does the user want it?
    begin
        if ((isnull(charindex('%', @full_table_name),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('_', @full_table_name),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('[', @table_name),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('[', @table_owner),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('%', @column_name),0) = 0) and
            (isnull(charindex('_', @column_name),0) = 0) and
            (@table_id <> 0))
        begin
            select @fUsePattern = 0 -- not a single wild char, so go the fast way.
        end
    end

    if @fUsePattern = 0
    begin
        select ....
        from
            sys.spt_columns_odbc_view s_cov

        where
            s_cov.object_id = @table_id -- (2nd) (@table_name is null or o.name like @table_name)
            ....
    end
```

The main point is that if you do not specify an owner, and do not use a pattern match, that the procedure uses `@table_id` to resolve the table name, so it is **impossible** to return more than one table.

So as far as I can tell your two options are - use a wildcard and accept the additional results, or pass a wildcard for `@table_owner`.

Comment: but before was transparent for me... any parameter I should put on the database for that?